# JavaScript Finding/Comparing and updating duplicate elements of metric/multi dimension array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-5

I have a metric/multi dimension array like below

```
[
[a,b,c,d],
[d,a,c,b],
[a,d,b,a],
[c,c,d,a]
]
```

I am required to update my given metric and keep track of change in a such a way

1. An element can repeat itself in one column only.
2. An element can not occur in other columns if it has occurred in a column.
3. If the above condition occur update the element by appending the column index to all its occurrence in a column.

In the above example element at index [1][1]('a' in row 2 and column 2) has occur in column 1. It and all its occurrence should update to 'a1'. Similarly 'd' and 'c' should update to 'd1' and 'c1' respectively.
In the next column Column 3, 'c', 'b', 'd' in column 3 should update to 'c2','b2','d2' because 'b' has occurred is column 2, similarly 'c' and 'd' has occurred before.
In next column Column 4 'd','b','a' will update to 'd4','b4','a4'.

Resulted metric will look like

```
[
[a,b, c3,d4],
[d,a2,c3,b4],
[a,d2,b3,a4],
[c,c2,d3,a4]
]
```

Keep track part
we can keep track like

```
var dictionary = [{"updatedValue":"originalValue"},...]
var dictionary = [{"a2":"a"},{"d2","d"},{"c2","c"},{"c3":"c"},{"b3":"b"},{"d3":"d"},{"d4","d"},{"a4":"a"},{"b4","b"}];
```

so far I have tried this

```js
  var flatData = [
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ['d', 'a', 'c', 'b'],
        ['a', 'd', 'b', 'a'],
        ['c', 'c', 'd', 'a'],
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < flatData.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < flatData[i].length; j++) {
            var element = flatData[i][j];
            for (var k = 0; k < flatData.length; k++) {
                for (var l = 0; l < flatData[k].length; l++) {
                    if (j != l) {
                        if (element == flatData[k][l]) {
                            flatData[k][l] = flatData[k][l] + l;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(flatData));
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Why wouldn't you post valid data so others don't need to make it valid in order to run it? Expected dictionary shown is a bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution uses a Map(could be plain object also) where first time a value is encountered a new entry is created that has an object `{col: firstColIndexFound, count:0}`.

Next time same value is encountered it checks stored column index and if different updates the count and creates a new value

```js
const data = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['d', 'a', 'c', 'b'],
  ['a', 'd', 'b', 'a'],
  ['c', 'c', 'd', 'a']
];


const dict = {};
const map = new Map();

for (let c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) { // c for colIndex
  for (let r = 0; r < data.length; r++) { // r for rowIndex
    const el = data[r][c];
    if (!map.has(el)) {
      // first time found create new entry
      map.set(el, {col: c, count: 0});
    }
    const entry = map.get(el);
    // if column index different than first column found update value
    if (c !== entry.col) {
      entry.count++;
      const nVal = el + entry.count;
      dict[nVal] = el;
      data[r][c] = nVal;
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
console.log(dict)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
  top: 0;
}
```